# CommandName not visible in source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, command, datalist

I have this code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Command1">
                    <img src="../images/image1.png" alt="" />
                </asp:LinkButton>                                         
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this code

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Command1")
    {      
        // Never drops here
    }           
}
```

The event is being triggered.
But when I debug, LinkButton1's CommandName is not visible in source code.
So, the if statement doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

**Edit :**

I realised that I have an other error my page that belongs this situation.
Then I used GridView rather than DataList and used the GridView's RowCommand Event and fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your attempting to obtain the `CommandName` from the `DataList` not the `LinkButton`.  Your code would work if you did the following:

```
protected void btnSample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Instantiate:
     var command = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandName;

     // Do additional logic.
}
```

I believe your intent is to actually do something on the Click Event.  If that isn't your case, you would need to `FindControl` on an event within your `DataList`, then instantiate the `LinkButton` to obtain the `CommandName`.  Hopefully this points you in the proper direction.

I would do a sample within the `DataList`, but without exact implementation and additional information I wouldn't be able to.  It would be similar to the above, just allocating the `Control` within the current control.